# Excel formula to extract a Sorted list of Top(N) Unique Distinct string/text values from multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Further requirements:

1. formula must be compatible with older versions like Excel 2010.
2. NO helper column.

Yes, I have seen similar questions and answers for **a single column** data.
I have seen answers suggesting to use **Excel Tables and/or Pivot Tables**.
I have seen formula answers using **R0C0 references** which eventually points to a blank cell which are not very reliable (to me).

Data is in a range of 10rows x 7columns = 70cells in B3:H12 containing string/text values as shown below.
[image: Data in B3:H12]

The question was first found on reddit at [r/vba](https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/1360h1x/excel_how_do_i_get_the_top_10_most_common_cell/).
My own answer using VBA's builtin Collections was given there.

What I seek here, is pure Worksheet formula to solve the titular question.
ONE last extra requirement would be:- to not have to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question because I can't find a single answer that meets my requirements.
So I'm sharing my own solution to help others with the same/similar requirements.
[image: data with answer]

Solution below for ease of copying:

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX($B$3:$H$12,
             MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,COUNTIF($B$3:$H$12, $B$3:$H$12)*(COUNTIF(K$2:K2, $B$3:$H$12)=0),1),
                            INDEX(COUNTIF($B$3:$H$12,$B$3:$H$12)*(COUNTIF(K$2:K2, $B$3:$H$12)=0),
                                         SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(1*(COUNTIF(K$2:K2, $B$3:$H$12)=0),0))=0,
                                         MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,MMULT(1*(COLUMN(INDIRECT("A:J"))>1),1*(((COUNTIF(K$2:K2, $B$3:$H$12)=0)*COUNTIF($B$3:$H$12,$B$3:$H$12))=
                                                                                                                                                                            AGGREGATE(14,6,COUNTIF($B$3:$H$12, $B$3:$H$12)*(COUNTIF(K$2:K2, $B$3:$H$12)=0),1))),1),
                                                        MMULT(1*(COLUMN(INDIRECT("A:J"))>1),1*(((COUNTIF(K$2:K2, $B$3:$H$12)=0)*COUNTIF($B$3:$H$12,$B$3:$H$12))=
                                                                                                                                           AGGREGATE(14,6,COUNTIF($B$3:$H$12, $B$3:$H$12)*(COUNTIF(K$2:K2, $B$3:$H$12)=0),1))),
                                                        0)),
                             0),
              MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,MMULT(1*(COLUMN(INDIRECT("A:J"))>1),1*(((COUNTIF(K$2:K2, $B$3:$H$12)=0)*COUNTIF($B$3:$H$12,$B$3:$H$12))=
                                                                                                                                                AGGREGATE(14,6,COUNTIF($B$3:$H$12, $B$3:$H$12)*(COUNTIF(K$2:K2, $B$3:$H$12)=0),1))),1),
                             MMULT(1*(COLUMN(INDIRECT("A:J"))>1),1*(((COUNTIF(K$2:K2, $B$3:$H$12)=0)*COUNTIF($B$3:$H$12,$B$3:$H$12))=
                                                                                                                AGGREGATE(14,6,COUNTIF($B$3:$H$12, $B$3:$H$12)*(COUNTIF(K$2:K2, $B$3:$H$12)=0),1))),
                             0)),"")
```

This is a pretty long, complex and resource-demanding array formula (but no requirement for CSE).
Therefore, YMMV for computers with low-resources and/or bigger dataset. And thus not for the faint hearted.
**You were warned!**

Cells B3:H12 contains `=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,65+2))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,65+2))` and +2 could be changed to control the randomness.
There are 2 parts concatenated with **&** which could be used to add further parts thereby changing the number of characters and hence, control the randomness thus changing the top10 values.

My formula answer is based on the formula [here](https://www.get-digital-help.com/unique-distinct-list-sorted-based-on-occurrance-in-a-column-in-excel/) for getting **Unique distinct values sorted based on frequency**.
I just adjusted the formula at aforementioned site to work for multiple columns by employing MMULT function and added INDEX functions to remove the need for CSE.

The formula works by eliminating duplicates using COUNTIFS starting from one cell above (=K2) and using AGGREGATE(14) to sort (max to min) after finding the location of most-occuring-text-value using MMULT.
The SUMPRODUCT part is for invoking error so that IFERROR will produce "" (BLANK) for values out of the TOP(N) as the formula got dragged down from K2 to N<sup>th</sup> cell or as far down as the user like.
[image: Using F9 on formula]
In the screenshot above (of the formula bar) is the formula after using **F9** on respective parts to clarify how it works.

---

In the screenshot below,
K3:K12 contains the formula solution.
L3:L12 contains the count of each top10 most occurences' counts.
N3:O12 contains VBA UDF solution entered by selecting N3:O12 and pressing **C**trl+**S**hift+**E**nter and
M3:M12 contains a COUNTIF check for VBA result in N3:N12.

VBA UDF should be used as in the screenshot below.
[image: how to enter VBA UDF]

VBA UDF code as follows (Yes, I know that we can use Dictionaries as well).
VBA's own Collection was intentionally used to exploit the ability to add items before or after a particular index in a Collection, contrary to a Dictionary.
The working code was not that long but the code for returning the data was longer because I wanted to provide the user with more choices.

```vba
Option Explicit

Function topNText(targetRange As Variant, _
                  Optional N As Long = 10, _
                  Optional returnHow As Variant = "1") As Variant
Dim arrTarget, i
Dim r As Long, c As Long, nextLargest As Long, loopEnd As Long
Dim collTarget As Collection
Dim tempCount As Long
Dim keyExists As Boolean
  arrTarget = targetRange.Value
  Set collTarget = New Collection
  For r = LBound(arrTarget, 1) To UBound(arrTarget, 1)
    For c = LBound(arrTarget, 2) To UBound(arrTarget, 2)
      On Error Resume Next
      keyExists = False
      keyExists = Not IsObject(collTarget.Item(arrTarget(r, c)))
      On Error GoTo 0
      If Not keyExists Then
        collTarget.Add Item:=Array(arrTarget(r, c), 1), Key:=arrTarget(r, c)
      Else
        tempCount = collTarget(arrTarget(r, c))(1)
        collTarget.Remove arrTarget(r, c)
        For nextLargest = collTarget.Count To 1 Step -1
          If collTarget(nextLargest)(1) > tempCount + 1 Then Exit For
        Next nextLargest
        Select Case nextLargest
          Case 0:
            If collTarget.Count > 0 Then
              collTarget.Add Item:=Array(arrTarget(r, c), tempCount + 1), Key:=arrTarget(r, c), Before:=1
            Else
              collTarget.Add Item:=Array(arrTarget(r, c), tempCount + 1), Key:=arrTarget(r, c)
            End If
          Case Else: collTarget.Add Item:=Array(arrTarget(r, c), tempCount + 1), Key:=arrTarget(r, c), After:=nextLargest
        End Select
      End If
    Next c
  Next r
  Select Case TypeName(returnHow)
    Case "String":
      ReDim arrTarget(1 To N)
      For r = 1 To N
        If r <= collTarget.Count Then arrTarget(r) = collTarget(r)(0) Else arrTarget(r) = ""
      Next r
      topNText = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrTarget)
    Case "Double":
      Select Case returnHow
        Case 1:
          ReDim arrTarget(1 To N)
          For r = 1 To N
            If r <= collTarget.Count Then arrTarget(r) = collTarget(r)(1) Else arrTarget(r) = 0
          Next r
          topNText = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrTarget)
        Case 2:
          ReDim arrTarget(1 To N, 1 To 2)
          For r = 1 To N
            If r <= collTarget.Count Then
              arrTarget(r, 1) = collTarget(r)(0)
              arrTarget(r, 2) = collTarget(r)(1)
            Else:
              arrTarget(r, 1) = ""
              arrTarget(r, 2) = 0
            End If
          Next r
          topNText = arrTarget
        Case Else: topNText = CVErr(xlErrNum)
      End Select
    Case Else: topNText = CVErr(xlErrValue)
  End Select
End Function
```

I regret that this answer turned out to be quite long but I just wanted to provide both the formula answer as well as VBA one for completeness' sake and hoping to be useful for people who might have similar requirements as me.